# Find the potential energy and sketch it

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

I'm given the equation $\ddot s=s-s^3.$

I'm asked to compute the potential energy and sketch it. I'm also given $m=1.$ To do this I have done the following:

$$F=ma=\ddot s=s-s^3=\frac{-dV}{ds}=\frac{-d}{ds}\bigg(\frac{s^4}{4}-\frac{s^2}{2}\bigg).$$

So $V=\frac{s^4}{4}-\frac{s^2}{2}.$

So the total energy is $$E=\frac{1}{2}\dot s^2+\frac{s^4}{4}-\frac{s^2}{2}$$

How do I sketch this?

Comment: The potential energy $V$ is just a function of $s$, a "sketch" is just a graph of this function.

Comment: @Travis Thank you. How would I sketch the phase portrait as well?

Comment: The phase portrait is a collection of level curves (perhaps marked with arrows to indicate direction) of $E$, regarded as a function of $(s, \dot s)$.